Blender 3.6 LTS Bone constraint highlight on custom shape bones?
When a constraint is placed on a bone that doesn't use a custom shape, it gets a green color highlight. Seems like by default, bones which use custom shapes don't get a green color highlight when a constraint is placed on them. Is there a way to enable this highlight for bones which use custom shapes?

You can't force a bone to have the constrained bone's highlight specifically, but since Blender 4.0 you can assign colors to bones no matter their custom shape or constrained state:

Although people usually use these colors to differentiate controllers that have specific jobs (I.E. light blue for tweak bones) or correspond to groups of body parts (main body in yellow, ik limbs in red, fk limbs in green, or red-blue for left-right limbs, ...).
Before v4.0, colors had to be set on bone groups instead:


I am forced to use 3.6 LTS version of Blender, I can't find this option. Is this possible in 3.6 LTS ?

see my answer edit

This only works when bones are not already assigned to a group. I wonder if it's possible to use a python script to check for bones with constraints on them and automatically change their custom shape color without using groups.

That would be possible if you even had a per-bone viewport color property to begin with. Which was introduced only since v4.0.
